# Chances of losing money in a foreign bank account

Tags: bank-account, germany, singapore

I am working in Singapore. I am going to move to Germany. So I am not sure if I should close my bank account. Is there any chance of losing money in the account (i.e. the bank confiscates it citing the reason that I am not there etc.)? Thanks.

Comment: The rules are different in different countries. Can you be specific about the countries involved.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any chance of losing money in the account

Assuming you are a Singapore citizen. The money is your's to claim. Note the account may go dormant [if you do not transact for a period] as per Bank's norms and they may charge a fees for such accounts.

Comment: I am not a citizen.